# We'll continue on our journey in the morning.(Is the 'on' preposition?)

Tags: prepositions

> We will continue on our journey in the morning.

Is the 'on' a preposition or an adverb?

Comment: It's an [**optional**] preposition. See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+continue+my+journey%2Cwill+continue+on+my+journey&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20continue%20my%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20continue%20on%20my%20journey%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwill%20continue%20my%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20continue%20on%20my%20journey%3B%2Cc0) showing that native speakers *don't* normally include that unnecessary preposition in this exact context. That's especially true of Brits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"on" is used as a preposition in your example.

It is optional, which means that both "continue our journey" and "continue on our journey" are acceptable. We can omit unnecessary prepositions if it doesn't change the meaning. For example:

> - There is no point *(in)* fighting over it.
> - Why can't I do it *(in)* my way?